# Is there any documentation on IdentityUnmarshal interface?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, com-interop, com+

Whenever I put my component into COM+ and call CoCreateInstance() on the client the following happens:

- the runtime instantiates the object (calls `IClassFactory::CreateInstance()`)
- the runtime calls `QueryInterface()` for the interface specified in the `CoCreateInstance()` call
- the runtime calls `QueryInterface()` for `IdentityUnmarshal` interface (`{0000001b-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}`)

The only thing I can find is the declaration in **comdef.h** that there exists **IdentityUnmarshal** interface with that interface id.

**ComDef.h**:

```
class __declspec(uuid("0000001b-0000-0000-c000-000000000046")) IdentityUnmarshal;
```

Is there any more information on it?

Comment: I can't even find it in comdef.h. All I find is the `extern` declaration of a CLSID named `CLSID_IdentityUnmarshal` in cguid.h, and no indication on which import library actually contains it...

Answer (score 2):

If I remember it correctly you may query for IdentityUnmarshal interface to define if you are dealing with proxy or not. If result is S_OK, then Proxy.

Update: check out [this discussion](http://marc.info/?l=ms-dcom&m=103440699420019&w=2)